# Divide a string into a certain number of substrings (C)

Tags: c, string

So, I have a certain file I read as input and load it into the memory, and obtain a  cstring char* text.

I want to split that string into a certain number of strings. Say I have 4 threads, for example, and I want each thread to print a certain "piece" of the string (not necessarily in order).

```
int num_threads = 4;
char *filename = "file.txt";
int file_size = load_file_to_mem(filename, &text); // I made this and it works.
int text_size = strlen(text);
int substring_size; // that would be the size of each substring
char to_thread[num_threads][block_size];
```

How can I split the *text string into 4 same sized substrings, that is, how can I find the block size so I can make each thread receive a substring of that size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I misunderstand the question, one way to do it is with the [ceil()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/ceil/) function: `num_threads - 1` substrings would each be of length `ceil(test_size / num_threads) + 1`. The remaining single substring would be of length `test_size - (num_threads - 1) * ceil(test_size / num_threads) + 1`.

You might do it this way because `num_threads` may not divide `test_size` evenly. Add one byte to include space for a null terminator character for each substring.

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Dividing the string is relatively easy: you have the string size, which you obtained from strlen, and you can compute the substring size by dividing the size by 4. You could then use something like [strncpy](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strncpy/?kw=strncpy) to copy just the amount of characters you need from the string you need to split into some temporary buffers, for example. Basically, for thread i you need to copy substring_size characters, starting from character substring_size * i (just use a pen and paper to see why this happens).

Now, you have 2 problems. One is that the size of the string may not be divisible by 4, which means that the strings printed from the threads will not be equal. The way you handle this is a matter of choice. One way to go would be:

```
base_substring_size = string_size / no_of_threads
remainder_substring_size = string_size % no_of_threads
for thread_id = 0 to no_of_threads:
    this_thread_size = base_substring_size
    if remainder_substring_size > 0
        this_thread_size += 1
```

This way, you have in the this_thread_size variable the exact size of the buffer for each thread. And do not forget about the NUL terminator.